# Some Workaround with scala map() and list

Tags: scala, data-structures

So, i got a list of tuples where tuple is pair of Int and `List[Int]`. I need to add one item in inner list to accomplish i tried to use map function and did like this

```
val list = List((7, List(2,4,18)), (10,List (4,8,12)), (12, List (5, 9, 13)))
list.map(e => mapFunction(e,16,10))
```

Above i want to insert in tuple with first value 10, in its list 16. Here is mapFunction :

```
 def mapFunction(element: (Int, List[Int]), i: Int, fileID: Int) : (Int, List[Int]) = {
        if (element._1 == fileID) {
            val list2 = element._2 :+ i
            (element._1, list2)
        }
        else
            element
    }
```

list 2 contains added value, but in the original list still unchanged. Is there some workaround?

Comment: if you do `val newList = list.map(e => mapFunction(e,16,10))` will this `newList` be what you need?

Comment: not exactly, the problem is a bit wider. I'm trying to implement inverted positional index in scala and my data Structure is `index: Map[String, List[(Int, List[Int])]]`. Since for each term i have to keep documentID and positions of this term in a document, for each document. So my problem is adding one more position for docID. If i just return new list every time i would need to remove and add term in the map which is stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this get at what you're after?

```
val lstA = List((7, List(2,4,18)), (10,List (4,8,12)), (12, List (5, 9, 13)))
val lstB = lstA.map{case (n,l) if n == 10 => (n, l :+ 16) ;case e => e}
```

A `map` call on the first `List` won't modify the list. It will create a new, modified, list.

To wrap it in a function might go like this.

```
// returns new List
def f(lst: List[(Int, List[Int])], i: Int, fileID: Int) : List[(Int, List[Int])] = 
  lst.map{case (n,l) if n == fileID => (n, l :+ i) ;case e => e}
```

---

**UPDATE**

It strikes me that if the `Int` part of your `(Int,List)` tuple is a "fileID" then it is probably required to be unique across the entire list of tuples, i.e. you'd never have `List( (10,List(2,4)), (10,List(3,5)) )`.  If that's the case then why not use a `Map` instead of a tuple?  That would guarantee uniqueness and simplify accessing the inner lists.  You might use a mutable `Map` to make data insertion easier.

```
import collection.mutable.{Map => MMap}

def insert(m: MMap[Int, List[Int]], fileID: Int, n: Int): Unit = {
  val newList: List[Int] = m.getOrElseUpdate(fileID, List()) :+ n
  m.update(fileID, newList)
}
```

So if you have a dataset like this...

```
val index: Map[String, MMap[Int, List[Int]]] =
  Map("key1" -> MMap(7 -> List(2,4,18), 10 -> List(4,8,12), 12 -> List(5, 9, 13))
    , "key2" -> MMap(8 -> List(2,4,18)))
```

...you can update it like so.

```
insert(index("key2"), 19, fileID = 9)
insert(index("key1"), fileID = 10, 16)
```

Now the dataset looks like this.

```
Map(key1 -> Map(7 -> List(2,4,18), 10 -> List(4,8,12,16), 12 -> List(5,9,13))
  , key2 -> Map(8 -> List(2,4,18), 9 -> List(19)))
```

Comment: not exactly, the problem is a bit wider. I'm trying to implement inverted positional index in scala and my data Structure is `index: Map[String, List[(Int, List[Int])]]`. Since for each term i have to keep documentID and positions of this term in a document, for each document. So my problem is adding one more position for docID. If i just return new list every time i would need to remove and add term in the map which is stupid, i guess.

Comment: I think, this is pretty much it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for comprehension to do a filter

```
val list = List((7, List(2,4,18)), (10,List (4,8,12)), (12, List (5, 9, 13)))
for {
     (k,v) <- list 
       newList = if(k == 10) 90 :: list else v  
    }yield(k,newList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scala standard library `Map` methods to neatly do this

```
val list = List((7, List(2,4,18)), (10,List (4,8,12)), (12, List (5, 9, 13)))

def update(i: Int, fileId: Int, list: List[(Int, List[Int])]): List[(Int, List[Int])] = list.toMap.get(fileId).map(list => map.updated(fileId, i :: list)).getOrElse(map).toList
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala>  def update(i: Int, fileId: Int, list: List[(Int, List[Int])]): List[(Int, List[Int])] = list.toMap.get(fileId).map(list => map.updated(fileId, i :: list)).getOrElse(map).toList
defined function update

scala> update(100, 7, list)
res16: List[(Int, List[Int])] = List((7, List(100, 2, 4, 18)), (10, List(4, 8, 12)), (12, List(5, 9, 13)))
```

`i` gets added to the corresponding List of `fileId`.